# Convert Mongodb timestampt to date

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, pymongo

Hi everyone I'm trying to convert mongodb timestamp to standart date with pymongo like 2021/08/22 I have this :

```
timestamp = result.get('timestamp')
```

I'm debugging with pycharm and with break point I see this:

```
timestamp: {'$date':1629203596651 }
```

How can ı convert it ? Many thanks.

Comment: `timestamp['$date']` ? 

Comment: Thanks for attention, but ı can not convert this integer to date I'm asking for it @Epsi95

Comment: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp['$date']/1000)` 

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Epsi95 his code solved my problem :

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp['$date']/1000)
```